# Laravel - How to set session variable at the start

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, controller

I'm beginning with Laravel, and I'm trying to set a session variable to see if the person who interrogates the API is a moderator or not.

I've already set the session variable with:

```
if (in_array(Session::get('email'), config('moderator')['moderator'])) 
{
    Session::put('is_moderator', true);
}
```

(BTW I'm using config to set the moderator, and I don't know if it's the best thing to do)

But I'm putting this code in a Controller's constructor, and this session variable is not available for the other controller. Where can I put this code to check at the beginning if a person is a moderator or not?

Comment: Perhaps you want to check out Spatie permissions it's a package which does all of permission, roles management out of the box. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

Comment: You can use middleware, or just check the session value later in the controller methods. But there are better solutions like using multiple auth guards or a package like Spatie permissions.